# Nested For Command help please

Tags: command-line-arguments

I am attempting to acquire the filename from the first part of a nested loop for use in the last part  ie (all file extracted from "09-10-15.zip" will be named "file1.09-10-15", "file2.09-10-15" ...

But I am getting null using set FileExt=%%~ni if I set the value static as a test, I see it is not reaching my last line.

I am now officially at a complete loss, any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r d:\ %%j in (*.zip) do (
set FileExt="%%~ni"
"c:\program files (x86)\winzip\wzunzip.exe" -d "%%j" C:\AllDWG\
for /r C:\AllDWG\ %%i in (*.dwg) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni.%FileExt%"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I am attempting to acquire the filename from the first part of a nested loop

```
@ECHO OFF
EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r d:\ %%j in (*.zip) do (
set FileExt="%%~ni"
"c:\program files (x86)\winzip\wzunzip.exe" -d "%%j" C:\AllDWG\
for /r C:\AllDWG\ %%i in (*.dwg) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni.%FileExt%"
)
```

There are several errors in your batch file.

```
EnableDelayedExpansion
```

This is the wrong syntax (see [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)), it should be `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

```
set FileExt="%%~ni"
```

The variable `i` is undefined at this point (your first `for` loop is using `%%j`), so it should be `set FileExt="%%~nj"`.

```
for /r C:\AllDWG\ %%i in (*.dwg) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni.%FileExt%"
```

You need to **use** the [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) here, as `%FileExt%` has a different value on each pass through the enclosing `for` loop, so it should be `!FileExt!`.

Try the following batch file (untested as I don't have an appropriate zip file):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r d:\ %%j in (*.zip) do (
  set FileExt="%%~nj"
  "c:\program files (x86)\winzip\wzunzip.exe" -d "%%j" C:\AllDWG\
  for /r C:\AllDWG\ %%i in (*.dwg) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni.!FileExt!"
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) - Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).

Comment: @DavdPostill Thank you, that worked perfectly.
it never occurred to me that %%~ni was referring to the counter, every example including the inline help had ni.
And thanks for the references, I had difficulty finding what I needed for this first attempt.